# How do I switch romantic partners after I've completed the main story?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm about to return to Dragon Age Inquisition to play Jaws of Hakkon, The Descent, and Trespasser. I completed the main story line, and I would like to change my romance from Josie to Cassandra for these. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, once you've completed the main storyline, romances may no longer be pursued, it seems. From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/dragonage/comments/2ql867/romance_after_main_story/):

> All romance discontinues after completing the main story.

The [IGN Guide for the final mission (Doom Upon All the World)](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/Doom_Upon_All_the_World) also confirms this:

> You can continue to play after beating the final boss, but some quests will cancel. All quests classified as Inner Circle Side Quests will cancel afterward, including any Sex and Romance quests.

As an aside, if you are playing as a female, you are unable to romance Cassandra at any point during the story.

Comment: It seems this answer (including the link provided), are pre-expansions, where romances can continue. My question is whether one can change the romance flag and develop a different romance in the expos.

Comment: @Khashir I did some research and it appears that DLC does not change this behavior. Doom Upon All the World locks your romance even in the post-game. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dragonage/comments/3kfwf9/no_spoilers_most_fulfilling_romance_for_trespasser/) is a thread of people discussing their favorite romances in Trespasser and it seems to be implied left and right that the romances in this are extensions of the romances from the main game.